# Proposal to change the 'Ask Different' site description on the Stack Exchange list of sites

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Users who have joined Ask Different will see the *Answers for your Apple questions* description at top left of all Ask Different pages (see below):

[image]

However, new users looking through the list of all Stack Exchange sites see the following description instead:

[image]

As you can see, the description they see is: *Q&A for power users of Apple hardware and software*.

I propose that we change the description used for Ask Different so that potential new users are not scared off from joining/asking questions simply because they think the site is for 'power users'.

More specifically, I propose either of the following:

<s>**Proposal 1** - Replace the description on the list of sites so that it matches the description used on the actual site (i.e. we use *Answers for your Apple questions* as the description in both locations).</s>

- **Proposal 2** - Edit the description on the list of sites so that the word 'power' is removed and it now reads *Q&A for users of Apple hardware and software*.
- **Proposal 3** - Edit the description on the list of sites so that it now reads *Q&A for enthusiasts and power users of Apple hardware and software*.

**UPDATE**

- I have removed Proposal 1 based on [grgarside's answer](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3024/168832).
- I have added Proposal 3.
- Below is some context on why I started thinking about this.

Yesterday I answered this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/283887/168832). It's since been edited, but originally it ended with:

> I’m sorry to ask such a newbie question, so if this isn’t the site (your description says “Q&A for power users of Apple hardware and software” and I am no power user), then a link to a resource for Mac newbies would be appreciated.

My reading of this is that the OP was hesitant to ask their question here. And, if they felt this way based on our description, then how many others might there be?

Finally, when a new user first goes to sign up, the description appears immediately above the <kbd>sign up</kbd> button (see below) and this may act as a final hurdle.

[image]

Comment: How do we vote on the proposals?

Comment: Monomeeth, the "standard" way to support voting is to post an answer for each option/proposal

Comment: Thanks @fsb for raising that. Patrix has clarified that for me and I've since edited my question based on grgarside's feedback. I've posted below two answers, one for each remaining proposal.

Comment: How do we discuss/debate the proposals?

Comment: @EJMak If voting and/or commenting here isn't enough, we can always use [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat). A couple of the moderators as well as grgarside, myself and others check it regularly. You can also ping one or more of us in your chat message (unlike comments, in chat you can ping multiple users). By ping I mean use `@Monomeeth`, `@patrix`, `@bmike`, `@grgarside`, etc.

Comment: Thanks to all who voted, I'm trying to actually getting the description changed to the proposal with the highest number of votes currently.

Comment: Thanks @patrix that's great! :)

Comment: I can update the text audience descriptions, but I won't be able to adjust [the header](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/apple/img/sprites.svg?v=dfd227049735) without calling in a designer. I updated [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/151/apple) already, but I wanted to check with you all on the banner. Is it ok if the header stays the same?

Answer (score 14):

### Proposal 3 -- Q&A for enthusiasts and power users of Apple hardware and software

Edit the description on the list of sites so that it now reads Q&A for enthusiasts and power users of Apple hardware and software.

Answer (score 6):

### Proposal 2 -- Q&A for users of Apple hardware and software

Edit the description on the list of sites so that the word 'power' is removed and it now reads Q&A for users of Apple hardware and software.

Comment: This one is better purely because it has fewer words.

Answer (score 1):

### Proposal 0 — It remains as it is.

1. Proposal 1 isn't suitable: the list of site descriptions are always of the form ‘Q&A for [scope]’.
2. Proposal 2 might be ok, but I don't think it's necessary. Many site descriptions use ‘power’ for the reasons discussed in:

   - [Why “Pro” in “Pro Webmasters”](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/why-pro-in-pro-webmasters).

As for me, (the newly added) [proposal 3](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3026/37797) sounds good.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I've since edited my question based on your feedback and have posted two answers below, one for each remaining proposal.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention, I do see your point that this may not be necessary, but decided to include some context to my question as to why it could be necessary. I'm happy to go with whatever the community census on this is.

Comment: @Monomeeth Sure, I like proposal 3 and added the title in case people want to vote for it to remain the same. I'll be voting for proposal 3, and I'll add that to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Proposal 1 -- Answers for your Apple questions

Replace the description on the list of sites so that it matches the description used on the actual site.

Comment: Thanks patrix for clarifying how voting on proposals should work. I've since edited my question based on grgarside's feedback and have posted below two answers, one for each remaining proposal.